# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 777600 into shape (720,1080,5)

Tags: python, moviepy

The following lines:

```
currentImageClip = ImageClip(r'path/to/image')
imageClipWithCaption = CompositeVideoClip([ColorClip(size=(1080, 720), color='black'), currentImageClip])
```

gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\samlb\Documents\folder\pythonFile.py", line 140, in makeVideo
    imageClipWithCaption = CompositeVideoClip([ColorClip(size=(1080, 720), color='black'), currentImageClip])
  File "C:\Users\samlb\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\moviepy\video\VideoClip.py", line 1157, in __init__
    np.tile(color, w * h).reshape(shape), is_mask=is_mask, duration=duration
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 777600 into shape (720,1080,5)
```

How can I avoid this error? Does it have something to do with the type of image I'm trying to composite?

This is the image I'm using (.png):

[image]

General Info: Python 3.9.13, moviepy 2.0.0.dev2-, Windows 10

Relevant moviepy code:

ImageClip in https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/master/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py
CompositeVideoClip in https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/master/moviepy/video/compositing/CompositeVideoClip.py

Comment: Can you please post more code? Such as the imports for `ImageClip` and `CompositeVideoClip` also the product of 720,1080,5 is exactly half of the required 7776000, maybe this can help you debug

Comment: Maybe try changing the `duration` argument

Comment: @Caridorc ImageClip is be found here: https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/master/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py
CompositeVideoClip is be found here: https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/blob/master/moviepy/video/compositing/CompositeVideoClip.py